# Angular Unit Test of a PRIME ng confirmation service

Tags: angular, unit-testing, service, primeng

First of all i am newbie at angular unit testing. I want to unit test the following method that removes a record from my data. The method is:

```
//Confirm Button for deletion


 confirm(name: string, id: any) {
      this.confirmationService.confirm({
          message: 'Are you sure you want to remove ' + name + ' from your list of Supporting Staff?',
          accept: () => {
             const index: number = this.data.indexOf(id);
              if (index !== -1) {
                this.data.splice(index,1);
                this.totalResults = this.data.length;
                this.updateVisibility();                
                this.alertMessage = { severity: 'success', summary: 'SUCCESSFUL REMOVAL', detail: 'You have successfully removed '+name+' from your Supporting Staff List.' };
                this.alertMessagesSrv.pushAlert(this.alertMessage);
               }   
          },
      reject: () => {       
      }
      });

  }
```

As you can see i am calling the confirmation service from PRIME ng and i open a dialog to ask the user if he wants to remove the selected record. (Data are my records).

This is my unit test:

```
 it('should remove a supporting staff from list', () => {
let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SupportingStaffComponent);
let app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
let dataService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(ProvidersService);
let spy = spyOn(dataService,'getSupportingStaffList').and.callThrough(); 
fixture.detectChanges();
let confirmFunction = fixture.componentInstance.confirm(app.data[0].name,1);
let confirmService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(ConfirmationService);
//fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('#btnYes').click();
let spyRemove = spyOn(confirmService,'accept').and.callThrough();

fixture.detectChanges();

console.log(app.data);
expect(app.data).toBeDefined();
});
```

So i am calling the service to load my data (dataService) and then calling my method to remove the first record. but nothing is happening. The unit test finishes succesfull but no data are removed.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 12):

You can use a jasmine fake to override the confirm dialogue and call the accept function as follows

```
spyOn(confirmationService, 'confirm').and.callFake((params: any) => {
      console.log(`fake calling accept`);
      params.accept();
})
```

Comment: A `// @ts-ignore` right above the `spyOn` is what I needed to make this work.

Answer (score 7):

on primeng > 7.1

```
spyOn(confirmationService, "confirm").and.callFake((confirmation: Confirmation) => confirmation.accept());
```

Answer (score 3):

you can try the below code. It works on primeng 8.0.0

```
spyOn(confirmationService, 'confirm').and.callFake((confirmation: Confirmation) => { return confirmation.accept(); });
```

Comment: Isnt that the same thing other answers have proposed?

Comment: @Croolman typescripts was complaining that confirmation.accept could be undefined, so I added a check in this style of confirmation and it worked

Answer (score 0):

if you are facing Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'
from the above method the use this

```js
spyOn(confirmationService, 'confirm').and.callFake((confirmation: Confirmation) => { return confirmation.accept?.(); });
```